# git error - fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Tags: git

I have encountered a strange problem.

- When I use `ssh` to git clone from remote repository, it always report fatal error:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1z8R.png)

And there is a transient connection, but it always seems to be disconnected after 7%.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDuEj.png)

- But when I change to use `https` to git clone from remote repository, it work fine.

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGU5N.png)

I have google it and try some solutions to similar problems, but they do not work. I also try debug git process, but it seems that there is no useful information.

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGTEy.png)

And it only occur when I use `git clone`. Once I have cloned repository to local, it work fine when I use `git pull` and `git push`.

This error really make me exhausted. I would appreciate it if someone can help me resolve this problem.
Thanks a lot.

By the way, My OS info is followed:

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIl3Q.png)

---

Sorry, my reputation value is too low, so I cannot post image in the page.

Comment: I have resolved it. It seems that the latest version of git change the process mode of sideband, which make the gitee server cannot normally reponse the `git clone` request. Just lower the protocol.version of git can help. `git config --global protocol.version 1`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and found out if I disabled the ethernet and only used wifi the issue went away.  I've suspected something is wrong with my ethernet port as it won't stay negotiated at 1Gb and always falls back to 100 Mb.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).